# How to pin GnuCash to the Windows 7 Start Menu?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

It's not possible via the "normal" means because the "Pin to Start Menu" is not displayed for the GnuCash link. I suspect it's got something to do with the fact that GnuCash on Windows is started via a script.

Any ideas on how to pin such a link in Win7?

There's some info on why programs won't pin in [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/32765.aspx) (with some due name calling) but it doesn't help in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the thread [Adding Batch Files to Windows 7 Taskbar like the Vista/XP Quick Launch](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/a44e74a1-20cd-4924-8f2b-3e6b688f1ad7) for several possible solutions.

Perhaps the easiest solution is to compile the script into an .exe that can be pinned.

If you wish for more info, please let me know more what kind of a script is used by GnuCash.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... the blog post I linked to actually *does* have the answer. It's in the comments. Duh...

Here it is:

- Put a shortcut to GnuCash on the desktop
- Right click on the shortcut to some other program that isn't already pinned to the taskbar, say MSPaint, select properties, and copy the target field
- Right click, select Properties on the GnuCash shortcut, and replace the target field with the copied info
- Pin the GnuCash shortcut to the taskbar
- copy the original target info from the GnuCash shortcut in the start menu
- Right click on GnuCash in the taskbar, then right-click on gnucash in the pop-up menu, select properties, and replace the original target info

Now the shortcut should work. The only problem is that **the shortcut isn't used to represent open windows, so when the program is run, it puts a separate copy of the shortcut in the taskbar.**

So, seeing as the bolded sentence completely defeats the entire point of pinning something to start menu, I'd say that alas, this is impossible with GnuCash 2.2.9 without any extreme hacks.